# data purity parameter

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

how do I get the integrity check job to only run a simple dbcc checkdb command with out the parameters. I had to disable the job because it is taking days to run instead of minutes. I could find no info on his page about this.

Comment: Never mind. I had to dig into the MS document on dbcc checkdb. Looks like I need to add the parameter physical only. My problem now with the Ola script is that physical only should be the default.

Comment: Why not just add that option to the SQL Server Agent job (that calls the DatabaseIntegrityCheck procedure): @PhysicalOnly = 'Y' ?

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation for Ola's Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html), he includes all the parameters you might want to use for non-default settings. The documentation is pretty thorough, and even includes examples. (Both examples below are copy/pasted from Ola's documentation.)

If you have a very large database (it sounds like you do), Paul Randall has some advice on running `CHECKDB` in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/10/19/checkdb-part-6-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/).

You can skip a bunch of checks and do the Physical Only check pretty easily:

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@CheckCommands = 'Checks',
@PhysicalOnly = 'Y';
```

If you want to do any of the specific steps that get skipped by `@PhysicalOnly = 'Y';` then you can explicitly specify those checks, as well. For example:

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@CheckCommands = 'CHECKCATALOG';
```

If recommend reading through Paul's advice, then leveraging the documentation to accomplish your exact goals.